# How to get the average of how many occurrences of numbers

Tags: algorithms

I have code that looks at numbers 1 - 5, and counts how many occurrences of those numbers appear in an algorithm. What is an algorithm for finding the average number of 1 - 5 by counting the occurrences? Example:

```
    1 occurred 10 times
    2 occurred 27 times
    3 occurred 15 times
    4 occurred 34 times
    5 occurred 56 times
```

How would you find the average number (1 - 5) using the occurrences? Thanks for any replies.

Edit: Yes there was a typo in the question. Fixed it.

Comment: what is "now many occurrences"? is there a typo maybe

Comment: i looked at it again. I think it says "how many". I'm not exactly sure how to spell "occurrences".

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Okay Avg is given by Avg= Total/Num. of Occurrence;
Now from your question what will be Total

```
Total = 1*10 + 2*27 + 3*15 + 4*34 +5*56 => 525;
```

Now

```
Num of Occurrence = 10+27+15+34+56 => 142;
```

so

```
Avg = 525/142 = 3.6971
```

I hope this solves your problem.